# Local excel file as data source in power bi report server

Tags: powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server

I have excel file as a data source for my power bi dashboard and this file based in one drive but not able to configure as data source in local power bi report server. Is there any solution to use this excel file and able to refresh at power bi report server? Any solution other than one drive where i can store my excel file to use as a data source?

I tried to set up connection with windows, basic authentication but not get success.